# How to troubleshoot DisplayPort over USB Type C?

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, displayport

I have a DisplayPort 1.4 (HBR2) monitor and a laptop with a Type C port capable of DisplayPort 1.4 as well. Everything works fine most of the time, however, occasionally, after I reconnect the laptop to the monitor or if it reconnects after waking up from the sleep, the connection gets restricted to HBR. The solution is to power-cycle the monitor, after which it goes back to HBR2.

I realise this sounds like a problem with the firmware of the monitor, however, regardless, my question is more general: how can I troubleshoot this kind of issues from Linux?

I expect that there should be *something* in the kernel to help me debug this, I tried poking around sysfs, but did not see anything relevant except for `/sys/class/typec/port0-partner/port0-partner.0/description`, which, unsurprisingly, confirms that the port is in the DP alt mode but nothing more. Ideally, I want to see some debug logs from the protocol negotiation steps that would explain which side restricts the link to HBR and why. Currently, I don’t even know how to check from my laptop whether the link is HBR2 or HBR (I only know it’s HBR because, luckily, the monitor tells me). The only symptom I see from the laptop side is that the mode that I want is not listed in `xrandr`, but how does `xrandr` know that mode is not available if it is listed in EDID?

Comment: Before anyone asks: the monitor is Dell U2720Q, its “USB-C Prioritization” is set to “High Resolution” which, according to the manual, corresponds to HBR2 + USB 2.0 data, which is exactly what I need.